# npm removes all packages at install or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I like to start using Node.js, so I made a plain vanilla installation on my Windows 10 computer. When I try to install additional packages (e.g. `npm install luxon`) or `npm update` then it removes all packages. It's basically a self-destruction, I have to re-install again to make it working:

```
C:\Programs\nodejs>npm update

removed 221 packages, and audited 1 package in 824ms

found 0 vulnerabilities


C:\Programs\nodejs>npm ls
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v17.0.1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
```

I tried version 16.13.0 and 17.0.1, both `.msi` file and `.zip` - all the same. Is there anything I missed.

Comment: You shouldn’t execute `npm` with a working directory equal to the installation directory of nodejs.

Comment: @t.niese Seriously? Is this intended behavior?

Comment: `npm` is intended to be used in your project directory or globally using `npm -g`. What do you expect  `npm update`  should do if you don’t run it in you project directory?

Comment: @t.niese I would it expect simply to work, i.e. install required packages without removing all others - or provide an error or at least a warning. `npm -g` also removes all packages. And for `npm update` I would never see any reason not running in installation folder in order to update the core packages.

Comment: `I would it expect simply to work` it works, but not as you expect. In the installation directory, you have only a `node_modules` directory containing the globally installed modules, but there is no `pacakge.json` or `package-lock.json` file because it is not a project. If you now call `npm update` or `npm install`, then `npm` assumes you want to handle that directory as a project directory, so it creates an empty `package-lock.json`  (and `package.json` in case of `install`), and then continues with the command (which removes all packages not present in `package-lock.json`).

Comment: For globally installed packages you will always use `-g`. So `npm install -g luxon`,  `npm update -g`, `npm ls -g`, …

Comment: `npm` serves two purposes. First, managing modules in your project managed by your `package.json` file using `npm <command>`. Second, installing node-based tools like linters, building tools, … globally like an application using `npm <command> -g`.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for explanation. Still, I would expect a warning like other package managers (e.g. `yum`) do, but let's accept it as it is.